# First Or Create

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I know using:

```
User::firstOrCreate(array('name' => $input['name'], 'email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password']));
```

Checks whether the user exists first, if not it creates it, but how does it check? Does it check on all the params provided or is there a way to specifiy a specific param, e.g. can I just check that the email address exists, and not the name - as two users may have the same name but their email address needs to be unique.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

`firstOrCreate()` checks for all the arguments to be present before it `finds` a match. If not all arguments match, then a new instance of the model will be created.

If you only want to check on a specific field, then use `firstOrCreate(['field_name' => 'value'])` with only one item in the array. This will return the first item that matches, or create a new one if not matches are found.

The difference between `firstOrCreate()` and `firstOrNew()`:

- `firstOrCreate()` will automatically create a new entry in the database if there is not match found. Otherwise it will give you the matched item.
- `firstOrNew()` will give you a new model instance to work with if not match was found, but will only be saved to the database when you explicitly do so (calling `save()` on the model). Otherwise it will give you the matched item.

Choosing between one or the other depends on what you want to do. If you want to modify the model instance before it is saved for the first time (e.g. setting a `name` or some mandatory field), you should use `firstOrNew()`. If you can just use the arguments to immediately create a new model instance in the database without modifying it, you can use `firstOrCreate()`.

Comment: I know. How can I specify to match on specific attributes. I only want to check on email and then if that matches update, if not create a new record.

Comment: Thanks, I've done: $user = User::firstOrNew(array('email' => Input::get('email')));  $user->name = Input::get('name'); $user->save(); Correct?

Comment: I changed it to firstOrNew, or should I have used firstOrCreate?

Comment: You can do it in one step: `$user = User::firstOrCreate(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'name' => Input::get('name')))`.

Comment: You can't do it all in one step. If a new user has the same email BUT a different name, it will create a new record (it should update it as email is unique). Hence why I can't do mass assignment. Unless you know of a fix?

Comment: Ok, in that case you can go with your second comment above. You can also use validation to check for unique values.

Comment: Thanks but whats the difference between firstOrCreate and firstOrNew? Also how would I use validation and then do a firstOrCreate - could you provide an example?

Comment: I've explained the difference in my answer. As for validation, I suggest you have a look at this: http://laravel.com/docs/validation

Comment: Thanks, so which should I use? Why would I need a new model instance vs getting the matched item?

Comment: Thanks, one last thing, so with firstOrCreate I would need to set the params like: firstOrCreate($params) but with firstOrNew I could do: $user = User::firstOrNew(array('email' => Input::get('email'))); $user->name = Input::get('name'); $user->save(); Correct?

Comment: I think @panthro talk about updateOrCreate function.

Comment: I have declared $fillable for mass assignment but firstOrCreate inserted an null record into database. Do you know why?

Comment: @lowerends, 

If not all arguments match, then a new instance of the model will be created.

Is it create a new record in Database ?

Answer (score 95):

As of Laravel 5.3 it's possible to do this in one step with `firstOrCreate` using a second optional `values` parameter used only if a new record is created, and not for the initial search. It's explained in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models) as follows:

> The `firstOrCreate` method will attempt to locate a database record using the given column / value pairs. If the model cannot be found in the database, a record will be inserted with the attributes resulting from merging the first array argument with the optional second array argument.

#### Example

```
$user = User::firstOrCreate([
    'email' => 'dummy@domain.example'
], [
    'firstName' => 'Taylor',
    'lastName' => 'Otwell'
]);
```

This returns the `User` for the specified email if found, otherwise creates and returns a new user with the combined array of `email`, `firstName`, and `lastName`.

---

This technique requires [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#mass-assignment) to be set up, either using the `fillable` or `guarded` properties to dictate which fields may be passed into the `create` call.

For this example the following would work (as a property of the `User` class):

```php
/**
* The attributes that are mass assignable.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $fillable = ['email', 'firstName', 'lastName'];
```

Comment: I feel it's important to mention that the fields you want committed to the database need to be added to `protected $fillable` on the corresponding model since it uses mass assignment.

Comment: WhyAyala notice is very important. Cause if you include in protected $fillable = ['email']; just keys from the first method firstOrCreate parameter your query would be like -> INSERT into tablename ('email',  `updated_at`, `created_at`) VALUES...

Comment: Thanks for this clear and direct answer! By the way, it should be written "to be set up" as separate words. "Setup" is only joined when used as an adjective (to describe the word that comes after it), or as a noun (a thing, e.g. "here is your new setup"). Please help bring back correct word joinery and visual reading!

Answer (score 5):

`firstOrCreate()` checks for all the arguments to be present before it finds a match.

If you only want to check on a specific field, then use `firstOrCreate(['field_name' => 'value'])` like:

```
$user = User::firstOrCreate([
    'email' => 'abcd@gmail.com'
], [
    'firstName' => 'abcd',
    'lastName' => 'efgh',
    'veristyName'=>'xyz',
]);
```

Then it checks only the email.

Answer (score 4):

An update:

As of Laravel 5.3 doing this in a single step is possible; the `firstOrCreate` method now accepts an optional second array as an argument.

The first array argument is the array on which the fields/values are matched, and the second array is the additional fields to use in the creation of the model if no match is found via matching the fields/values in the first array:

[See the Laravel API documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_firstOrCreate)

Comment: Great complementary info. Could be made as a comment, not per se an answer ; )

Answer (score 4):

You can always check if in current instance the record is created with the help of

```
$user->wasRecentlyCreated

So basically you can

if($user->wasRecentlyCreated){

 // do what you need to do here

}
```