# check if record is already exist against user id and update if exist and insert if not exist - using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am trying to update record against user_id if its already exist and insert new record if not exist against user_id in laravel:

But my user id is inside $doctorProfile['user_id']
data is inserting but user id inserting as NULL:

My Controller Code:

```
          if($request->has('doctor_profile'))
        {
            $doctorProfile = $body['doctor_profile'];


                 $data_array = [

                'user_id' => $doctorProfile['user_id'],
                'medical_credentials' => 
               $doctorProfile['medical_credentials'],
                'registration_number' => 
           $doctorProfile['registration_number'],
                'registration_expiration_date' => 
          $doctorProfile['registration_expiration_date'],
                'dea_number' => $doctorProfile['dea_number'],
                'dea_expiration_date' => 
       $doctorProfile['dea_expiration_date'],
                'dea_issue_date' => $doctorProfile['dea_issue_date'],
                'npi_number' => $doctorProfile['npi_number'],
                'billing_title' => $doctorProfile['billing_title'],
                'billing_employment_type' => 
       $doctorProfile['billing_employment_type'],
                'other_employment_type' => $doctorProfile['other_employment_type'],
                'nadean_number' => $doctorProfile['nadean_number'],
                'upin' => $doctorProfile['upin'],
                'wcb_authorization' => $doctorProfile['wcb_authorization'],
                'wcb_rating_code' => $doctorProfile['wcb_rating_code'],
                'wcb_date_of_issue' => $doctorProfile['wcb_date_of_issue'],
                'hospital_privileges' => $doctorProfile['hospital_privileges'],
            ];

            $medId = MedicalIdentifiers::firstOrCreate(['user_id' => $doctorProfile['user_id']], $data_array);
            $medId->save();

        }
```

Comment: What do you get if you dump your $data_array before calling firstOrCreate? like dd($data_array);? can you show us the data

Comment: Where do you declare `$body` variable? Could you tell us how the request is structured?

Answer (score 0):

you can make it easier

```
 if($request->has('doctor_profile'))
     MedicalIdentifiers::firstOrCreate($request->all());
```

`firstOrCreate()` checks for all the arguments to be present before it `finds` a match. If not all arguments match, then a new instance of the model will be created.

If you only want to check on a specific field, then use `firstOrCreate(['field_name' => 'value'])` with only one item in the array. This will return the first item that matches, or create a new one if not matches are found.

The difference between `firstOrCreate()` and `firstOrNew()`:

- `firstOrCreate()` will automatically create a new entry in the
  database if there is not match found. Otherwise it will give you the
  matched item.
- `firstOrNew()` will give you a new model instance to    work with if
  not match was found, but will only be saved to the    database when
  you explicitly do so (calling save() on the model).    Otherwise it
  will give you the matched item.

Choosing between one or the other depends on what you want to do. If you want to modify the model instance before it is saved for the first time (e.g. setting a name or some mandatory field), you should use `firstOrNew()`. If you can just use the arguments to immediately create a new model instance in the database without modifying it, you can use `firstOrCreate(`).

from: [First Or Create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178464/first-or-create)